# Implement json in python Centos8

Tags: python, json, centos8

I have a .py script to modify a json file. However what I'm doing is loading a json file and then modify it with my code. What I have is the next ñ:

```
 with open('example.json', 'r+') as file:
    dictionary_data = json.load(file)
    .  
    .(code)
    .
    .
    .
 new_file = open("modify.json", "w")
```

I'm trying something like this but I got the next error in CentOs8

```
with open(str(sys.argv[1:]), 'r+') as file:
  dictionary_data = json.load(file)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 12, in <module>
    with open(str(sys.argv[1:]), 'r+') as file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "['helloWorld.json']"
The HelloWorld file is in the same directory as the main.py
```

Is there any solution to automatize the json file? So when I'm using the command `python3 main.py example.py helloWorld.json` to generate a modify.json from that helloWorld.json file

I'm using Centos8 and the path of the files are /root

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `str(sys.argv[1:])` is `"['helloWorld.json']"` which is not file.
try using:

```
with open(str(sys.argv[1]), 'r+') as file: # for example.json

with open(str(sys.argv[2]), 'r+') as file: # for helloworld.json
```